# iPhone frame rate -and the speed of changing images

Tags: iphone, objective-c

When simulating on Xcode i can see that the frame rate is about 60fps .
I also know that the human eye, can see between 10-12 frames in a second and define them.

My question is , lets say i would like to replace an image on the iPhone, as fast as i can, for example running all the numbers images again and again , what will be the max speed that can be produced without any lags(sure that my eye cant see that but anyway) , and what would happen if i will put it to be faster than the max ? will it just jump over some numbers ?

What does it means when i see 60fps ? why not 30? can we see the difference ?

is there any docs or specs to understand the exact screen spec ?

Thanks .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The iPhone 4s, iPhone 5, and newer devices can update the screen at 60 frames per second.  The iPhone 4 and older devices can update at 30 fps.  If your code updates each frame faster than the device can update the screen, it will simply skip frames.

As for whether fps is noticeable, that depends on the person.  I cannot stand a framerate lower than 30 and I can clearly tell the difference between 30 and 60.  Some people can't tell the difference.  Some people prefer 30 to 60.  It really depends on who you ask.  But in general, the higher the framerate, the smoother the animations will be.

Answer (score 3):

As for whether fps is noticeable, that depends on the person and the circumstances. The Human Visual System is not easily defined! For example, the bigger the screen, the higher the need for high frame rate - so one could argue that 30 fps may be enough for a phone, but if you hold the display close to your eyes and your eyes is tracking a moving object, surely it is possible to see the difference between for example 30 and 60 fps.

In fact, there is no fixed fps number a person can see. If you imagine a giant screen and your eyeballs tracking a small baseball traveling from one end to the other of that screen, the image of the baseball "projected" onto your retina will jitter back-and-forth with a frequency depending on the frame rate, a phenomenon called strobing.

Even if the frequency of this jitter is higher than the so called "critical flicker frequency", where your eyes are able to perceive the flicker, you will still see a blurring of the ball on your retina which is dependent on the frame rate, and in this situation you may easily be able to distinguish between 30 fps and 60 fps and even higher. The higher fps the sharper you will see the ball. Ask any hardcore PC gamer if he thinks 30 fps is good enough!

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question (and possibly your second if I understand what you are asking)  here is a little background:

FPS is used to describe how many frames your graphics card can output each second.   Refresh rate is typically measured in Hz and represents how often the screen can refresh.  If your FPS is faster than your Hz then the screen simply won't display all the images you show.  This can lead to Tearing which can be resolved by using Vsync.  Vsync will synchronize your FPS and refresh rate to resolve the issue.

Does this help?